# Are there any historical Churches that do not recognize the 66 books from the Protestant Bible?

Tags: bible, canon, protestant-bible

There are differences in the Bible Canon between Protestants, Roman-Catholics and Eastern-Orthodox and Oriental-Orthodox. But is the Protestant Canon of 66 books the common **denominator**? Aka, are there any historical Churches that do not recognize any of the 66 books from the Protestant Canon?

Comment: A lot of overlap with https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/52597/do-any-non-swedenborgian-christian-denominations-have-a-smaller-biblical-canon-t

Comment: Which gives the answer of Swedenborgianism.

Comment: Depends; would differences in content between various versions of canonical books (e.g., Masoretic vs. Septuagint) count ? Would ancient Gnostics count as a historical church, who rejected the entire Old Covenant ?

Comment: @Lucian No, I was thinking more as Churches that are alive today and that where founded till the... let's say second century

Comment: Would apostolic churches whose New Testament canon consisted of only twenty-two books for most of their bi-millennial history, but eventually came to consist of twenty-seven only over the last two or three centuries, count ?